# How can I print a servlet context attribute in EL?

Tags: el, servlets

Is there a way I can get a attribute set in `ServletContext` in EL so that it ends up as a JavaScript variable?

I am setting it as

```
context.setAttribute("testing.port", "9000");
```

I tried retrieving it like

```
alert("port" +'${testing.port}');
```

I am just getting a blank.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the period (`.`) in the key name. EL interprets the period as a call to an accessor method named `getPort`<sup>1</sup> on whatever object `testing` references. [Fetch the value from the appropriate implicit object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705187/escape-jsp-el-using-jstl-tags-dot-character):

```
${applicationScope['testing.port']}
```

or just use a different key:

```
${testingPort}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Yes, this is a simplification of what really happens. It may also look for a predicate getter named `isPort`, or try `Map#get("port")`.</sub>

Comment: `${servletContext}` doesn't exist. There's `${pageContext.servletContext}`, but that isn't what you want. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij

Comment: Ahhh, thanks very much. That clears it up... my JSP is getting rusty!